# iPhone 6 display works on charge screen but not when powered on

Tags: iphone, screen

Strange issue with an iPhone 6 here that was sent in for repair.. it had been run over but was still in good cosmetic condition. The base of the phone was bent into a slight s shape with the top of the headphone socket being snapped, and a bend the other way on the other side of the case. The screen glass was intact but the lcd was smashed and the digitizer only worked in some places. I noted that the screen image could be improved by tapping the phone on the desk, the screen being mostly a mess of same coloured lines but the UI became visible enough (ghostly) to be understandable after a few taps

I’ve replaced the screen with a new glass/lcd/digitizer assembly and seemed to have worked out as the “I’m out of charge, plug me in” / “charger is registered, battery is charging” screens showed up perfectly. I let it sit overnight to charge and in the morning it had powered on but the screen was entirely black except for maybe 20 pixels in various places on the screen. The phone itself seems to work, as I can hear Siri voiceover (activated before screen replacement) talking to describe the screen contents

Anyone have any ideas what could be done to improve the situation? (Tapping it on the desk doesn’t seem to work)

I might be able to use voiceover sufficiently to enter the passcode and get the phone to trust iTunes/back it up, but it’d be interesting to know if this is a fault that can be remedied..